# Thread safe vs. non thread safe implementations of a counter

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, atomic

This is a school assignment, but I really need some help with this one. I can't for the life of me figure out why the two different versions of `nextValue()` behave differently - one is thread safe and the other one is not. Can somebody give me some pointers in the right direction at least?

I've included both versions in the same class below, but obviously they're not both present in the code...

```
public class NumGenerator {

    static final int MIN_VALUE = -256;
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 255;
    static final int INITIAL_VALUE = MIN_VALUE -1;


    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(INITIAL_VALUE);
    private final AtomicInteger resetCounter = new AtomicInteger(0); 

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    // Thread safe
    public int nextValue() {
        int next = counter.incrementAndGet();      
        if (next > MAX_VALUE) {                         
            synchronized (lock) {                       
                next = counter.incrementAndGet();   
                if (next> MAX_VALUE) {                  
                    counter.set(MIN_VALUE); 
                    resetCounter.incrementAndGet();
                    next = MIN_VALUE;
                }

            }
        }
        return next;   
    }

     // Non thread safe
     public int nextValue() {
        int next = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (next > MAX_VALUE) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                int i = counter.get();
                if (i > MAX_VALUE) {
                    counter.set(INITIAL_VALUE);
                    resetCounter.incrementAndGet();
                }
                next = counter.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic of both the code seem to be different. IMHO, both the functions are thread safe. However as mentioned, both functions might return a different output than expected.

Comment: You're right, they return different outputs... but why? To me they look functionally identical. What am I missing?

Comment: `counter.get();` and `counter.incrementAndGet(); ` are different. So you will get different output

Comment: Ok, but that's inside the outer IF-statement... you mean that the difference is that another thread could come between `int next = ...` and `synchronized...` and screw up the result? I guess so, but there's still the second IF-statement?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say values were : MIN_VALUE = -1, MAX_VALUE = 3, counter = 3.

**Code 1:**

```
synchronized (lock) {                       
                next = counter.incrementAndGet();   
                if (next> MAX_VALUE) {                  
                    counter.set(MIN_VALUE); 
                    resetCounter.incrementAndGet();
                    next = MIN_VALUE;
                }

            }
```

1. It increments the value of counter and then uses it for comparison.
2. So the value of next becomes 4. `if(next > MAX_VALUE)` becomes if(4>3) this would change the value of next to -1 and return it.

**Code 2:**

```
synchronized (lock) {
                int i = counter.get();
                if (i > MAX_VALUE) {
                    counter.set(INITIAL_VALUE);
                    resetCounter.incrementAndGet();
                }
                next = counter.incrementAndGet();
            }
```

1. It assigns the value to counter then compares.
2. The value of `i` would still be 3. `if(i > MAX_VALUE)` becomes if(3 > 3), which its not so returns 3 as the output.

`incrementAndGet` and `get` are different.
So the code with same values is returning different output.
one is incrementing the value first then checking the condition, the other is checking the values first and then performing an operation.

Even the code inside the if( variable > MAX_VALUE) would result in different output.

So this has nothing to do with Thread safety.

Comment: I just figured out what the difference is. You are correct that the difference lies in using `IncrementAndGet()` vs just using `get()`, but I don't agree that it doesn't have anything to do with thread safety. Both codes work in a single thread, but when called concurrently there is a chance for the value to get changed by another thread between the first `incrementAndGet()` and `get()`, hence the second IF-statement is invalid since it should be equal to the first IF-statement. Basically the code should assume that `counter` can be anything at the second IF, just as if there was no outer IF.

Comment: @BadCash That should Ideally not be the case. As the synchronized block should ensure both the codes are thread-safe. So both `increamentAndGet()` and `get()` will have no effect as only one thread will be given a chance to execute inside the block. Now coming to thread safety, there is an issue outside the synchronized block `int next = counter.incrementAndGet();` when 2 threads increment the value at the same time, their local copy of next will have different values. So when considering this line both the codes are not thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, but in the first version there is an identical `next = incrementAndGet(); if( next > MAX_VALUE )` inside the synchronized block, making it thread safe. I guess it's the same effect as making the entire method `synchronized` and just having one IF-statement, but with the added benefit that it won't block the method for other threads for all the cases when the first IF-statement is false...

Answer (score 0):

Think Both methods are thread safe logically. because in both methods synchronized is used. and synchronized block is used for thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

Both are Thread-Safe. Maybe you can paste out the code how you are testing them. The issue might be there.